# Bazel build doesn't link the dependency .so files

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, nvidia, bazel

I'm trying to write a codelet in NVIDIA isaac SDK which uses bazel build. The following is the case. I have a A.so file which is linked with B.so. But using A.so I have written a codelet and mentioned A.so in the srcs column of cc_library(). The compilation is successful, but during the runtime, the final binary is unable to find B.so file.

Given below is a sample cc_library rule which mentions all the .so files in lib/ directory. When I run the application, It is able to link only  A.so files and even though other dependency .so files are in the same path, it is not able to pick them up.

After deploying, the final .so files are put in some directory like the following
"_solib_arm64-v8a/_U@xxx_Uaarch64_Ujetpack42_S_S_Cxxx_Uaarch64_Ujetpack42___Uextern"al_Sxxx_Uaarch64_Ujetpack42_Sisaac_Upackage_Slib/"

I see all the dependency .so files in that directory. But it wont pick them up unless I manually export the path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

cc_library (

```
name = "xyz",

srcs = glob(["lib/*.so*"]),

hdrs = glob(["include/*.h*"])+
       glob(["include/opencv2/*.h*"])+
       glob(["include/opencv2/core/**/*.h*"])+
       glob(["include/opencv2/highgui/*.h*"])+
       glob(["include/opencv2/imgcodecs/*.h*"])+
       glob(["include/opencv2/videoio/*.h*"])+
       glob(["include/opencv2/imgproc/**/*.h*"]),
includes = ["include"],


visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
deps = [
    "@com_nvidia_isaac//third_party:cuda",
    "@libvtk_aarch64",
    "@openni_dev_aarch64"
],
```

)

Q : Is there any other way to get the links working without specifying it in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Shared object (.so) libraries aren't meant to be picked up from arbitrary directory at whim, it'd be a security issue, because someone could supply a hacked library to replace legit one. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is meant for quick tests.  Lookup uses paths from
`/etc/ld.so.conf`.

For gcc there is way to tell linker where to look, with -R flag,  described here: [Can't find .so in the same directory as the executable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/279068/cant-find-so-in-the-same-directory-as-the-executable).
In case of Bazel it probably can be solved by `linker_flag:`.